# список rgb-цветов

Tags: c++, color

Где можно найти заголовочный файл или библиотеку с большим количеством псевдонимов для `rgb`-цветов?

Comment: Это, как минимум, основывается на том, как хранится цвет. QColor, другой какой, или Вам чисто компоненты? Да и они могут быть в границах [0;1] или [0;255].

Comment: @AivanF. массивы из 3 компонентов, типо
`const unsigned char red[] = {255, 0, 0}`

Comment: Маловероятно, что будет где-то такой заголовок, проще самому сделать. Много цветов с разными кодами есть на [английской Вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names).

Comment: [ловите](http://www.astrouw.edu.pl/~jskowron/colors-x11/rgb.html) (а сам файл /usr/lib/X11/rgb.txt)

Comment: @avp не могу разобраться, как этот файл скачать

Comment: @dimitrius нужно установить linux :)

Answer (score 2):

например, в исходниках x-сервера: https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/plain/os/oscolor.c